# How to send complex model with files in flutter via chopper to spring

Tags: spring, flutter, kotlin, chopper

Assume we are creating a social network site.
I try to send a model that contains multiple comments each comment could contain multiple files.

`MainModel`

```
List<Comment> comments;
String uid;
.... //other properties here
```

`Comment` class should look like:

```
String comment;
List<http.MultipartFile> attachments;
... other data of comment
```

The question is:
How to send this `MainModel` via flutter (`chopper` lib) and receive it in spring boot.

I saw threads where people just send a simple file with flutter to spring boot, but never seen threads where people send complex model with multiple files

Comment: if you are asking about flutter, why did you tag kotlin?

Comment: @mohsen because I ask, how to receive it in spring boot (my project is in spring boot + kotlin) - that's why I tag it kotlin.